# A single word that means "to push yourself"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means "to push yourself". Endurance sort of fits, except that it means enduring a situation where one can't change things. I'm looking for someone pushing themselves when they have a choice to stop or back out.

(In case you're wondering- I want it for the caption of a motivational poster)

ETA: I'm looking for a word that would fit more in the context of "to push yourself to continue when you're bored with what you're doing" rather than "to push yourself when things are physically / mentally challenging".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use ["disciplined":](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discipline)

> A controlled behaviour; self-control

Someone who is disciplined won't easily let himself back out.

Comment: Hmm. A "disciplined" person might force himself to take a break and thereby avoid making mistakes through lack of concentration. A keen but inexperienced person could be prone to misguided persistence.

Comment: I chose this as the answer as opposed to strive (thank you @FumbleFingers!) because I am looking for an overtone of self-control rather than effort.

Comment: @dmr: Fair enough. The question text makes that clearer now than it did originally. But the title and first paragraph are still more evocative of efort/endurance than effort/discipline. Judging by the votes though, I think quite a few people just appreciate my effort to rescue **strive** from linguistic obscurity! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: My immediate thought when I read the title (before reading any answers) was "strive" and +1 to your answer for that.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: I think it's a great word. I must admit I'd always thought *Thou shalt not kill; but needst not strive officiously to keep alive* was actually part of [The Hippocratic Oath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocratic_Oath). In fact it isn't, but I still like to think it *could/should* be.

Answer (score 42):

[strive](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=strive&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=GBxpToadAcKo8AO_vdEa&sqi=2&ved=0CBgQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=2078bdb7a7494626&biw=1427&bih=892) - *make great efforts to achieve or obtain something*

[persevere](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy&hl=en&newwindow=1&biw=1427&bih=892&tbs=dfn:1&source=hp&q=persevere&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c3eddaea38dfa36e) - *continue in a course of action, in the face of difficulty, or with little chance of success*

The choice mainly depends on whether you want to emphasise the difficulty or the continuing, but it's important to note that unless the context clearly rules it out, there's a risk of *perseverance* carrying those overtones of potentially futile effort.

Answer (score 25):

**Perseverance** comes to mind....

Comment: This is not a verb

Comment: "Persevere" is a verb.

Answer (score 10):

[Persist](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=piffle&pbx=1&oq=piffle&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=102401l103355l0l103697l6l6l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&biw=1024&bih=581&cad=cbv&sei=0_FoTvHyOoaDgAec-cWJDQ#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=Persist&pbx=1&oq=Persist&aq=f&aqi=g-s1g9&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=2950447l2951950l8l2954314l7l7l2l0l0l0l1393l5670l6-1.4l5l0&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=db40fb2adbcd0a27&biw=1024&bih=581) - you'll eventually find it worthwhile.

Answer (score 10):

Also "Driven" is a way to show that you push yourself.

Comment: beat me to the punch

Comment: Although when I think of someone that is driven I imagine someone that is pushed by some outside force, perhaps genetic disposition, alien encounter (perhaps aliens, lightning), or a mystical force.

Answer (score 6):

**Exert:** To exert oneself.

1. Apply or bring to bear (a force, influence, or quality).
2. Make a physical or mental effort

Answer (score 5):

Perserverance fits, as does steadfastness

> Perserverance: continued effort to do or achieve something despite
>   difficulties, failure, or opposition : the action or condition or an
>   instance of persevering : steadfastness

(from http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perseverance)

Although if you are looking for a word that means "to push yourself", "to perservere" would probably be the best fit.

Answer (score 4):

Resolute:

> - firmly resolved  or determined; set in purpose or opinion.
> - characterized by firmness and determination, as the temper, spirit, actions, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Sticktoitiveness** (Stick-to-it-iv-ness).  Extremely nonstandard but I've heard it said.

Comment: [It's a perfectly cromulent word!](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cromulent)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to eliminate "yourself" from the expresion. Without it every synonym will sound impersonal.
Another good synonym for "to push yourself" is "to challenge yourself" and from there to one word I have seen people using "self-challenge".

Answer (score 1):

The term I'd use is "self-starter." Someone who exerts themselves without being told to do so.

Answer (score 1):

> Endure

I like it better than persevere but they're both good.

Answer (score 1):

**Strain**. By definition, it implies an effort beyond one's normal ability.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking too much at other answers:

- Focused
- Targeted
- Committed

Answer (score 1):

DRIVEN
(is much shorter than 30 chars)

Comment: If your answer is so short you need to add filler, add an example sentence. This is more helpful than a short peeve.

Comment: driven is a short word that means someone is driven.

Comment: I beat you to the punch.

Comment: appears you did sir. appears you did. I'll go vote for you ;)

Comment: lol, i voted for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

PSR mentioned business jargon, which reminded me of gaming jargon.

Grind is used commonly among gamers to convey working towards a distant goal often though a repetitive or boring task. The grind is often used to refer to the type of work you mentioned. I presume these uses may refer to the phrase, “Putting one’s nose to the grindstone.” All these phrases seem to me to convey a sense of work which attempts to wear-down the person attempting the task.

Answer (score 1):

"Toil" may be one answer. Toil - to work hard

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it might be used in a business setting so why not invent some jargon, with bonus points for using nouns as verbs?  In that spirit I suggest to "hero", to "robot", or to "CPA" through a situation, depending on what connotation you wish to convey.

Answer (score 0):

*Strive*, *strain*, *labor*, and *fight* are all synonyms for "push yourself," depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

persistence, determination, resolution, resolve, doggedness, tenacity, diligence, application, assiduity, dedication, commitment, purpose, purposefulness, constancy, steadfastness, stamina, endurance, indefatigability

Chambers Thesaurus

Comment: I think picking just one which you think would be *best* would improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> "to push yourself to continue when you're bored with what you're doing"

Sounds like progress for the sake of progress. *Progressive* might be a good fit, though it lacks the sense of determination that other words have, and has political connotations that could be distracting.

I don't have any other new words to suggest, but it might help the thinking process if you consider particular reasons to push yourself in a given situation.

Answer (score 0):

Our company's personal-evaluation jargon for this is *stretch*.